# Responsive Image Gallery

Tags: 7, views, javascript, theming

I want to create a responsive Image gallery block. I have used [Views Slideshow Liquid Carousel](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_liquidcarousel) module for this but that is not working properly, It breaks when the screen is too small. I want a carousel like display of images with responsive skin like http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/, I have also tried this plugin but this plugin is not working properly can't find why. So is there any other way or plugin for this.

Comment: I solved this using flexslider plugin

Answer (score 3):

Trying to use these modules may help you (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Responsive Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_images):

> ... integrates the [Responsive Images library created by Filament Group](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images/tree/cookie-driven).
>
> The purpose of this library is to load images in different sizes based upon
>   the resolution of the browser loading the page. This allows for mobile-optimized images.
>
> ... provides a "Responsive Images" image field formatter for which you can select
>   both a small (mobile-optimized) image style as well as a large (for normal screens) image style. The image style configuration options are provided by Drupal core.

- [Responsive images and styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/resp_img):

> ... solves the problems with images and responsive themes, it allows you to define multiple image style suffixes and their corresponding maximum width.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 module for responsive images will be in the picture module, a Drupal 7 Version exists today: [Picture](https://drupal.org/project/picture)

Using the picture module, instead of the other available alternatives, will probably help in upgrading pages from 7 to 8.